# Define network interface as the default gw independently of IP

Tags: ip, route, gateway

I know how to assign a default gw to an interface with an IP

```
ip route add default via <host> dev <dev>
# e.g.
ip route add default via 192.168.0.101 dev eth0
```

The problem is that the IP of eht0 in my scenario is externally managed. Therefore the previous command will not work if the IP of eth0 is changed.

Is there a simple way to assign an interface as the default gw, independently of the IP it has?

- **Note**: The interface is not UP when booting the machine.
- **Note 2**: My interface is a 3g modem, therefore I also DONT KNOW the
  gateway IP before I make a petition to connect.

Comment: You don't assign an interface as a default gw. The "via"  IP address is the address of the router, not your host. If the addresses are externally managed (using DHCP?), then the default gw should also be externally managed.

Comment: There are two ways for the IP address to be "externally managed": It gets the IP address via DHCP, and the same DHCP packet also contains the default route, which should be set automatically. Or, it is a point-to-point connection, which when established via `ppp` etc. will also give you the IP of the other endpoint, which you can then use for a route. TL;DR: There is **no** way to "set a gateway independent of the IP", that's not how it works. You set the default route automatically as a reaction of your interface getting the address. Details depend on the type of your network interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some modem cards are doing [Proxy ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_ARP). That means you can tell the default route is through the card *without gateway* and your system will start issuing an ARP request for any IP (eg ARP for 8.8.8.8 following a `ping 8.8.8.8`), since the card looks like ethernet, as if the whole Internet was on the LAN. If the card is doing proxy ARP, this will work. Example with a card named *wwan0*:

```
ip route add default dev wwan0
```

If it's not doing proxy ARP, nothing much will happen beside a timeout after 3s with the message "Destination Host Unreachable" for any Internet IP.

You have to test and see what's the result.

Comment: btw: choosing interface's own's IP as gateway (as apparently in OP's question) has the same effect as not choosing it at all (as in my answer): relies on external proxy ARP too.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
IP=$(ip a s dev eth0 | awk '$1=="inet" { split($2,I,"/") ;print I[1] }')
ip route add default via $IP dev eth0
```

you might replace eth0 with a variable.

I fail to se the point if eth0 (or whatever modem interface) is DHCP managed, most likely proper routing will be provided.

Comment: Even though your script works I am looking for another solution. The script gets the IP of the interface and then adds  the routing option. Therefore, if my IP changes from time to time, I need to re-run it. My intention is to create a "rule" which allows to forward the packets to the interface without the need to check every other time if the IP of the interface has changed.

Comment: Modem connection didn’t provide you with a default route ? That sounds strange

Answer (score 0):

ping 8.8.8.8
There are two ways for an IP address to be "externally managed": This gets an IP address through DHCP, and the same DHCP package also contains the default route, which must be set automatically. Or, it is a point-to-point connection, which when made via ppp etc. It will also give you an IP from another endpoint, which you can then use for the route. TL; DR: There is no way to "set the gateway independent of IP", that's not how it works. You set the default route automatically as a reaction to the interface you get the address. Details depend on the type of your network interface. - on June 11 at 8:06 p.m.